# OllyDbg catching/throwing exceptions

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

Every time I am trying to debug something with OllyDbg 1.10 (on Windows 7 32-bit), it keeps throwing exceptions for no reason. I skip them with `Shift + F7/F8/F9`, and at the end it throws an exception saying `EIP = 00000000`.

Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: what's your ollydbg version? Get the newest at http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html Also does it really do that on every exe you open? What OS are you using? Did you install plugins? More details please!

Comment: @龚元程  am using odbg110 and yeah with every exe :S , ruining it on win7 32bit

Comment: Do you have all the necessary plugins so your ollydbg is not detected by the program? Maybe you have to unpack the program first? The program was written in C, Delphi, .NET?

Comment: @César Bustíos  was written in C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sub>The following applies to OllyDbg 1.10; for other versions, YMMV.</sub>

**Options > Debugging Options > Exceptions**

[image]

This setting allows you to set OllyDbg to ignore each/any exception thrown (use specific numbers for specific exceptions or `00000000 .. FFFFFFFF` to ignore all).

---

Also, for your convenience, I'd recommend the following settings for OllyDbg, in case you don't have them:

#### Start analysis of main module

`Options -> Debugging Options -> Analysis 1`

[image]

With this option activated Olly will analyze the program being debugged at start.

#### Highlighting jumps and calls

`Options -> Appearance -> Defaults -> Default syntax highlighting -> Jumps'n'calls`

Or, for current window, using right click:

[image]

#### Show jump path

`Options -> Debugging Options -> CPU`

[image]

With this options you can see the path of the jumps.

Finally, I recommend virtualize XP inside your Windows 7 with a tool of your choice, as it may make your debugging easier.

Comment: @César although your hints are extremely helpful (I honestly wonder why those settings ain't the default ones!), I'd strongly suggest to put them in a separate self-answered Q&A (e.g. "What initial settings are helpful for people new to OllyDbg?"), since AFAIK they are **completely** unrelated to OP's question - also, putting that Q&A on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ would make it even better IMO.